# .HTACCESS not to redirect a specific file

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a web structure where all my files have extension .php and I am using .htaccess to remove .php from the url.
So the file is www.abc.com/ab.php ----> www.abc.com/ab

This works fine, However, I have few files that are requested in form and are manipulated using JS (this isn't ajax) and because of .htaccess it doesnt work.
Can any one let me know how can I exclude "formfile.php" file from not getting redirected to "formfile"

Here is my code :-

```
  RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.php\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line of code: `RewriteRule ^ajax.php.*$ - [PT]`

Comment: Accept Answer: D Thanks